# How to insert a lot of facts in StatefulKnowledgeSession (Drools)

Tags: mysql, drools

I want to insert a lot of facts in StatefulKnowledgeSession.

But It not reach the fireAllRules() part

My facts have 10k facts. get in MySQL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbnoh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tJEU.png

and stale

**My Code :**

```
public void runDrools() {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    starttime = new Date();

    if (PersonalCondition1.isSelected() && ConvenienceDay_jCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Rules1_Conv_Schedule.drl", getClass()), ResourceType.DRL);
    } else if (PersonalCondition1.isSelected() && !ConvenienceDay_jCheckBox.isSelected()) { 
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Rules1_Non-Conv_Schedule.drl", getClass()), ResourceType.DRL);
    } else if (PersonalCondition2.isSelected() && ConvenienceDay_jCheckBox.isSelected()) { 
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Rules2_Conv_Schedule.drl", getClass()), ResourceType.DRL);
    } else if (PersonalCondition2.isSelected() && !ConvenienceDay_jCheckBox.isSelected()) { 
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Rules2_Non-Conv_Schedule.drl", getClass()), ResourceType.DRL);
    }
    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
        System.err.println(kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
    }

    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

    boolean InBuild, NearbyBuild, OutBuild;

    if (NearbyBuild1.isSelected()) {
        InBuild = false;
        NearbyBuild = true;
        OutBuild = true;
    } else if (NearbyBuild2.isSelected()) {
        InBuild = true;
        NearbyBuild = true;
        OutBuild = true;
    } else {
        InBuild = false;
        NearbyBuild = false;
        OutBuild = true;
    }

    if (Control3_jCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        Amount_Test = (Integer) Amount_jSpinner.getValue();
    } else {
        Amount_Test = 0;
    }

    Check check = new Check(Amount_Test, InBuild, NearbyBuild, OutBuild, Status_JLabel);
    ksession.insert(check);

    Data_List list = new Data_List();
    ksession.insert(list);

    if (Control3_jCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        Amount_Test = (Integer) Amount_jSpinner.getValue();
    } else {
        Amount_Test = 2;
    }

    try {

        rs_ro = stm_ro.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM room");
        while (rs_ro.next()) {
            String code = rs_ro.getString("ro_code"),
                    capa = rs_ro.getString("ro_capacity");
            Room room = new Room(code, Integer.parseInt(capa));
            ksession.insert(room);
        }

        rs_sch_exam = stm_sch_exam.executeQuery("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(sch_date,'%a') AS day FROM schedule_exam ORDER BY sch_date ASC");
        while (rs_sch_exam.next()) {
            String date = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_date"),
                    day = rs_sch_exam.getString("day"),
                    start = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_start"),
                    end = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_end"),
                    subj = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_subject"),
                    depa = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_depart"),
                    sec = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_sec"),
                    room = rs_sch_exam.getString("sch_room");
            Schedule schedule = new Schedule(date, day, subj, sec, depa, room, start, end);
            schedule.setConnect(getHost(), getUser(), getPass());
            ksession.insert(schedule);
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        rs_peo = stm_peo.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM control_exam");
        while (rs_peo.next()) {
            String code = rs_peo.getString("ce_code"),
                    depart = rs_peo.getString("ce_department"),
                    room = rs_peo.getString("ce_room"),
                    sun = rs_peo.getString("ce_sunday"),
                    mon = rs_peo.getString("ce_monday"),
                    tue = rs_peo.getString("ce_tuesday"),
                    wed = rs_peo.getString("ce_wednesday"),
                    thu = rs_peo.getString("ce_thursday"),
                    fri = rs_peo.getString("ce_friday"),
                    sat = rs_peo.getString("ce_saturday"),
                    max = rs_peo.getString("ce_maxcontrol");
            if (max.equals("")) {
                max = MaxDays_jSpinner.getValue() + "";
            }
            Control_Exam controlExam = new Control_Exam(code, depart, room,
                    Integer.parseInt(sun), Integer.parseInt(mon), Integer.parseInt(tue),
                    Integer.parseInt(wed), Integer.parseInt(thu), Integer.parseInt(fri),
                    Integer.parseInt(sat), Integer.parseInt(max));
            controlExam.setConnect(getHost(), getUser(), getPass());
            ksession.insert(controlExam);
        }

        rs_sub = stm_sub.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM subject");
        while (rs_sub.next()) {
            String code = rs_sub.getString("su_code"),
                    name = rs_sub.getString("su_name"),
                    educator = rs_sub.getString("su_educator");
            Subject subject = new Subject(code, name, educator);
            System.out.println(" subject:" + subject.getCode());
            ksession.insert(subject);
        }

        rs_nea = stm_nea.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nearby");
        while (rs_nea.next()) {
            String build = rs_nea.getString("nb_build"),
                    near;
            if (NearbyBuild1.isSelected()) {
                near = rs_nea.getString("nb_nearby") + "," + build;
            } else {
                near = rs_nea.getString("nb_nearby");
            }
            Nearby nearby = new Nearby(build, near);
            System.out.println(" nearby:" + nearby.getBuild());
            ksession.insert(nearby);
        }
        databasetime = new Date();

        if ((((databasetime.getTime() - starttime.getTime()) / 1000) / 60) >= 1) {
            DatabaseTime = MTime.format(databasetime.getTime() - starttime.getTime()) + " นาที";
        } else {
            DatabaseTime = MSTime.format(databasetime.getTime() - starttime.getTime()) + " วินาที";
        }
        ksession.fireAllRules();
        ksession.dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Amount_Test = -1;
        Manage_Schedule.this.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Simple Rule (Rules1_Non-Conv_Schedule.drl) :**

```
import schedule.Schedule
import schedule.Nearby
import schedule.Room
import schedule.Subject
import schedule.Control_Exam
import schedule.Check
import schedule.Data_List
rule "Add control exam first in Build"
    salience 14
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getInBuildState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( max > 0 )
        $room : Room( build == $controlExamCondition.getBuild() ) 
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() , 
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() )
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval($schedule.getStateEmptyCE1()) 
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam1( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 1: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam first nearby Build"
    salience 11
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getNearbyBuildState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $near : Nearby(  )
        $room : Room( build == $near.getBuild() ) 
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( build memberOf ( $near.getArrayNearBy() ) , max > 0 )
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() , 
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval($schedule.getStateEmptyCE1()) 
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam1( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 1: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam first out Build"
    salience 0
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getOutBuildState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( max > 0 )
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval($schedule.getStateEmptyCE1()) 
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam1( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 1: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam second in Build"
    salience 14
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getInBuildState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( max > 0 )
        $room : Room( build == $controlExamCondition.getBuild() ) 
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() , 
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval( !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE1() && $schedule.getStateEmptyCE2() )
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam2( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 2: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam second nearby Build"
    salience 11
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getNearbyBuildState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $near : Nearby(  )
        $room : Room( build == $near.getBuild() ) 
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( build memberOf ( $near.getArrayNearBy() ) , max > 0 )
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() , 
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval( !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE1() && $schedule.getStateEmptyCE2() )
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam2( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 2: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam second out Build"
    salience 0
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getOutBuildState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( max > 0 )
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule(  ) from $scheduleCheck ,

                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval( !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE1() && $schedule.getStateEmptyCE2() )
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam2( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 2: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam third in Build"
    salience 14
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getInBuildState() && $check.getThirdControlState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( max > 0 )
        $room : Room( build == $controlExamCondition.getBuild() ) 
        eval($room.getCapacity() > $check.getAmountThirdControl())
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() , 
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval( !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE1() && !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE2() && $schedule.getStateEmptyCE3() )
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam3( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 3: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam third nearby Build"
    salience 11
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getNearbyBuildState() && $check.getThirdControlState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $near : Nearby(  )
        $room : Room( build == $near.getBuild() ) 
        eval($room.getCapacity() > $check.getAmountThirdControl())
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( build memberOf ( $near.getArrayNearBy() ) , max > 0 )
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() , 
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval( !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE1() && !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE2() && $schedule.getStateEmptyCE3() )
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam3( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 3: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end

rule "Add control exam third out Build"
    salience 0
    when
        $check : Check( )
        eval( $check.getOutBuildState() && $check.getThirdControlState() )
        $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
        $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam( max > 0 )
        $room : Room( ) 
        eval($room.getCapacity() > $check.getAmountThirdControl())
        $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                            educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
        $schedule : Schedule( room == $room.getCode() ,
                                subject == $subject.getCode() , 
                                date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() &&
                                starttime <= $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() && endtime > $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) 
        $controlExamList : Data_List( ) from accumulate( $scheduleCECheck : Schedule( date == $scheduleCheck.getDate() ,
                              starttime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() || endtime == $scheduleCheck.getStarttime() ) ,
                              init( Data_List DataList = new Data_List(); ),
                              action( DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl1()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl2()); DataList.addData($scheduleCECheck.getControl3()); ),
                              result( DataList ) )
        $controlExam : Control_Exam( code not memberOf ( $controlExamList.getArrayCode() ) ) from $controlExamCondition
        eval( !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE1() && !$schedule.getStateEmptyCE2() && $schedule.getStateEmptyCE3() )
    then
        modify( $schedule ) { setControlExam3( $controlExam.getCode() ) };
        modify( $controlExam ) { checkMax( $schedule.getDate() ) };
        $check.setTextState("เพิ่มผู้คุมสอบที่ 3: "+$controlExam.getCode() + " ในห้องสอบ: " + $schedule.getRoom() + " วันที่: " + $schedule.getDate() + " เวลา: " +  $schedule.getRealStartTime() + " - " + $schedule.getRealEndTime());
end
```

*Sorry my English is bad.*

Comment: If you comment out all those `ksession.insert(...)` calls, does it print more lines? If not, it isn't a Drools problem. - You are catching `SQLException` but not reacting to it - not a good strategy. Add a stackdump there.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space // pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7tJEU.png

Comment: Most likely: your rules are causing an excessive amount of activations to be created, and this causes the OOM exception. - You may have to post your rules so we can assess them.

Comment: You haven't answered my first question, and you haven't added the rules - so don't nag.

Comment: laune,may I send my java with you?

Comment: Java and DRL would be required.

Comment: All of them and database.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8tBdoCk8qI5ZnRsaVFNSFJnS2M&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks not like a drools problem.

You are running out of memory because you have a huge number of objects in your project. In case you have over 10k facts, you create more than 10k objects just because your `System.out.println(new Date().toLocaleString().....` logs.  Remember String is not a primitiv datatyp.

You have to tweak your code and increase the maximum heap size of JVM (default is around 64mb).

Comment: These `new Date().toLocaleString()...` objects are immediately free for garbage collection - that's not the issue. Something else is causeing the out-of-memory exception.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to run these rules with likely numbers of facts for `Control_Exam`,
`Room` (even when restricted to a building), `Subject` and `Schedule`. Consider these patterns on a left hand side:

```
    $scheduleCheck : Schedule( )
    $controlExamCondition : Control_Exam()
    $room : Room( build == $controlExamCondition.getBuild() ) 
    $subject : Subject( educator1 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                        educator2 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                        educator3 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                        educator4 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ),
                        educator5 not in( $controlExamCondition.getCode() ) )
```

You are creating a number of activation resulting from the Cartesian product of all `Schedule`, `Control_Exam`, `Room` (restricted to a building) and a certain subset of `Subject` facts.

And you have about 50 such rules, and they are not well written, e.g., rule "Add control exam first in date / Convenience State 1-5 in Build":

- `Schedule()` appears twice
- `Control_Exam` appears twice
- constraints aren't evaluated as early as possible (which should reduce the number of activations)
- Creating a `Data_List()` as a wrapper for a set (array or List) adds unnecessary overhead

I'd have to try and understand the data model in full to propose improvements.

I suppose this is meant to solve a planning problem. Typically, such problems have a big, even huge, search space, and if you can't reduce this very quickly, resource requirements (both time and space) explode.

Drools Planner has been developed for solving such problems, but the approach (while still using rules) is quite different.

Comment: 1) Learn Drools Planner and use that. 2) Try a conventional approach, using procedural (Java) code. 3) If you have the time: study all the Drools literature and examples you can get. 4) If you have a good requirements document: get help. - As I wrote in my answer: it's no good making any suggestion without knowing the datamodel and the requirements. From what I guess about the problem, a satisfactory solution is more than you can expect from the web. - I'll ask someone regarding Planner and write another comment.

Comment: I agree with laune. For clarity I 've posted a separate answer for the Drools Planner (= OptaPlanner) way with links.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) (= new name for Drools Planner)'s Exam timetabling problem.

[Here's a video on exam timetabling with OptaPlanner and Drools.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_bl6E7aiNY)

[Here is a list of the exam score rules.](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/examination/solver/examinationScoreRules.drl#L35) Notice that they don't contain only scoring requirements, not search requirements.

To understand why creating/evaluating all possible solution combinations is insane (they scale exponentially), [read this blog article about search space size](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/27/IsTheSearchSpaceOfAnOptimizationProblemReallyThatBig.html).